# Spreadsheet component with VBA support

Tags: .net, excel, vba, spreadsheet, spreadsheetgear

I am looking for a .Net spreadsheet component that could also execute the VBA contained in Excel files.

I found [Spreadsheet Gears](http://www.spreadsheetgear.com/) to be very nice for manipulating and allowing the user to edit Excel files, but on spreadsheets that use VBA for calculations, well, these don't work.

So, apart from Excel itself, are there any other components that can execute VBA?

Comment: I don't know about VBA, but there is (or was) a .NET component that would execute VBScript. I used it with .NET 2.0. The syntax is very similar, and it might work for code that doesn't need tight integration with a specific workbook (like a function library or something).

Comment: SpreadsheetGear will not execute your VBA code, but you can implement your user defined functions in C# or VB.NET and your workbooks will work with SpreadsheetGear. See the "Custom Functions" sample on this page for an example: http://www.spreadsheetgear.com/support/samples/calcengine.aspx

Answer (score 1):

You can directly execute office macros from .NET

**Eg: vb.net**

```
 objExcel = New Excel.Application
 objExcel.Workbooks.Open(FileName:="c:\test.xls", ReadOnly:=True)
 objExcel.Run("test.xls!test.test")
```